# Bluno + PS3 controller?

Tags: bluetooth, bluno

I'm seeking information about connecting a PS3 controller using Bluetooth to an Arduino.

Bluno cards could be an integrated solution for that, but can it work?

Also, I've seen some tutorials using a USB shield + a Bluetooth dongle: in this case, at some setup steps a USB connection is needed between the PS3 controller and the Arduino. It is still the case with a Bluno card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not strictly impossible, using a PS3 controller with the Bluno (ATmega + CC254x) is essentially impractical.

The PS3 controller is either a USB device, or a *classic* Bluetooth device.

- A USB device can only communicate with a USB host.  Neither the ATmega nor the CC254x on the Bluno is capable of being a USB host.  An add-on USB host shield would cost more than simply buying a platform suitable for fulfilling the *entire* requirement natively.
- The CC254x only speaks Bluetooth Low Energy.  It is not compatible with classic Bluetooth devices. To communicate with the PS3 via Bluetooth you would need to add a Bluetooth classic radio to the system.

If you wish to use a PS3 controller you should pick a non-Arduino platform having native USB Host capability or native classic Bluetooth capability.

Otherwise, if you wish to use an Arduino-like platform, pick an earlier generation controller with either a very old wire-per-function interface or a simple synchronous serial interface, for example a PS2 controller.